# How do I update a properties file dynamically?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

My application is a batch process that pulls environment variables from an application.properties file. The password that I use must be updated every few months. I would like to automate the password update process and save the updated password in the properties file so it can be used in future runs, but any updates I try to make are not propagated to the application.config file.

When I run in Intellij, there are no errors, but the file is not updated. When I run the application as a jar, it gives:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:{localpath}\application.jar!\BOOT-INF\classes!\application.properties (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
```

How do I dynamically update the application.properties file within the jar or do I need to create a new properties file outside of the jar when the application first runs??

EXAMPLE CODE SNIPPETS BELOW:

properties.config:

```
username=user
password=password123
```

Application.java:

```
    //get properties
    prop = new Properties();
    InputStream input = null;
    try {
        input = new FileInputStream(f);
        // load a properties file
        prop.load(input);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        logger.error("Error reading application.properties", ex);
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (input != null) {
            try {
                input.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    //update properties
    prop.setProperty("TESTSTRING", "testvalue");

    //write to properties file
    OutputStream os = null;
    try{
        File f = new File(Application.class.getClassLoader().getResource("application.properties").getFile());
        os = new FileOutputStream(f);
        prop.store(os, comments);
    }catch(IOException ex){
        logger.error("Error updating application.properties", ex);
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if(os != null){
            try{
                os.close();
            } catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Did you thought about setting up a config server and pull properties from there. . It is specifically designed for these purposes.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to update a.jar file which is currently loaded in JVM and running. For other jars you can use command `jar uf jar-file input-file(s)` - see [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/update.html). But in general consider extracting your properties to external location.

Comment: @pvpkiran It's a single job with low throughput. Having a separate config server or a config table in a database seems like way too much overhead.

Comment: Then you need to extract the properties .. one of the common approaches is to have a managed file(application.properties) in Jenkins.

Comment: URL.getFile() **does not** convert a URL to a valid file name.  It just returns the path and query portions of the URL, with all percent-escapes intact.

Answer (score 1):

Properties of an application that may change according to the running environment should **never** be packaged inside the packaged  component.
It should be not hard coupled to the component and it should also be modifiable if required without modifying the packaged component.
Besides, properties may contain confidential information (as in your case : username and password). 
So it should be preferably stored directly on the target environment.

For example, one of the cloud native application principles from [Heroku/twelve factors](https://12factor.net/config) (that are also good practices in general) is "storing the configuration in the environment".

So updating the properties file inside the packaged component has to be absolutely avoided for the same reasons.
Besides doing it makes the state application more hard to reproduce if an errors occurs.

---

In your case, simply fill `username` and `password` properties in a specific properties file according to the target environment and store this file on the environment.

Then you have just to run the application by specifying this properties file.
For example for windows :

```
java -jar yourApp-1.0.jar --spring.config.location=file:///D:/application-target-env.properties
```

Here is the reference documentation about it : 
[24.2 Accessing command line properties](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files)

Comment: I'm looking into this, but already running into issues. Looks like my jar is not able to find the application.properties even in the default directories (current directory, /config) or if I try to configure it via command line options - getting NullPointerException from Classloader call. Will I need to also change how I am trying to access the file to use this method?

Comment: `java -jar yourApp.jar` with an existing `config` folder at this level that contains the `application.properties` should work. How are you sure that it doesn't work ? Anyway, using this method is the way to follow. I think that you should create a new question to explain this problem and give all required information to reproduce your problem. I am sure someone will show how to solve it.