# How to change values dynamically in application.properties file in JAVA

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a simple requirement, I wanted to set rest urls in my application.properties file

e.g

```
endpoint.some-service.path=http://example.dev
endpoint.some-service.magazines=${endpoint.some-service.path}/api/v1/magazines
endpoint.some-service.magazine=${endpoint.some-service.path}/api/v1/magazines/1234
endpoint.some-service.magazine.articles=${endpoint.some-service.path}/api/v1/magazines/1234/articles
```

I know how to change `http://example.dev` to `http://example.prod` by using ENV variables e.g `http://example.${someenv}`

But I dont know how to change `1234` dynamically or with the value I get from DB. Please help, Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43378305/how-do-i-update-a-properties-file-dynamically

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43378305/how-do-i-update-a-properties-file-dynamically This will be useful.

Comment: I have to call these apis using restTemplate and need to modify `1234` to some another id, I dont want to override the application property file

Comment: You can change '1234' to something very generic e.g <id> and while you're are making this api call, replace the <id> with you dynamic value for the url.

Answer (score 0):

`UriComponentsBuilder` and `UriComponents` are handy when changing the path variable.

First of all we need to change our application property file to

```
endpoint.some-service.magazine.articles=${endpoint.some-service.path}/api/v1/magazines/**{id}**/articles
```

In Java class we can get the application property using

```
public class ServiceClient {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    public String getAllArticlesURL() {
        env.getProperty("endpoint.some-service.magazine.articles");
    }
}
```

Then we can write the rest call

```
ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = null;
// URI (URL) parameters
Map<String, String> urlParams = new HashMap<>();
urlParams.put("id, "1234");
UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(this.serviceClient.getAllArticlesURL());
UriComponents uriComponents = builder.buildAndExpand(urlParams).encode();
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(uriComponents.toUri(), HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
```

Hope this answer helps new bees :-)